# Highlighting inside JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

Is it possible to highlight some parts of text in `JEditorPane`, when I have a list of Strings to highlight?
Using HTML tags is not possible (text will contain some tags).
Is creating cutstom `EditorKit` necessary?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getHighlighter().addHighlight(start, end, 
             new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.red));
```